# How to do group_by for the db.currentOp() json array in mongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, bash, shell

I need to write a shell script for generating a formatted output.

```
{
    "desc" : "conn98242",
    "threadId" : "140393378481956",
    "connectionId" : 98242,
    "client_s" : C1,
    "active" : true
 }

 {
  "desc" : "conn98249",
    "threadId" : "140393378481920",
    "connectionId" : 98249,
    "client_s" : C2,
    "active" : true
}
{
  "desc" : "conn98252",
    "threadId" : "140393378485620",
    "connectionId" : 98296,
    "client_s" : C1,
    "active" : true
}
```

This is the output from db.currentOp().

I need to get a result **json** file like

```
{

"client_s" : C1
"count" : 2

}
{

"client_s" : C2
"count" : 1

}
```

Comment: Try this `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$client_s",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])`

Comment: how we can use this command since its not associated with any collection ?

Comment: `db.currentOp(
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$client_s",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
)`

Comment: `mongo <ip>:<port>/admin -u uname -p ***  --eval " status  = db.serverStatus()

if(status.connections.current > 10 )
print('success')

db.currentOp().inprog.forEach(
  function(op) {

if(op.client_s)

db.currentOp( { $group: { _id: '$client_s', count: { $sum: 1 } } } ).forEach(
  function(p) {

printjson(p)


  }
)
`

Comment: still i am getting error while excuting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the **[`db.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.aggregate/#db.aggregate)** helper with [`$currentOp` on the admin database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#use-currentop-on-an-admin-database) in the first stage and group the results of that operation in the second stage:

```
use admin
db.aggregate([
   { $currentOp : { allUsers: true } },
   { $group : { 
       _id: '$client_s',
       count: { $sum: 1 }
   } }
])
```

or running the admin command:

```
db.adminCommand({
   aggregate : 1,
   pipeline : [ 
        { $currentOp : { allUsers : true } }, 
        { $group : { 
            _id: '$client_s',
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        } }
    ],
    cursor : { }
})
```

Comment: How we can write this script in eval and assign the value into a json variable?

Comment: @vampo458 This part of the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#scripting) should help you

Comment: mongo shell is throwing error when i do  `db.aggregate([....`  error -db.aggregate is not a function.

Comment: Im using 3.2 version. i guess so that this error is throwing.